# Book for lattice field theory for somebody with basic understanding of Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, lattice-model, wilson-loop, lattice-gauge-theory

I have finished a first course in Quantum Field theory and I'm looking to get into lattice field theory (mostly QCD on the lattice). What are some resources for somebody wanting to learn how things are done on the lattice?

I'm looking for books or notes (better if they also contain exercises) that cover everything from discretization on the lattice, Wilson lines, tiling, etc, to various techniques used nowadays for lattice calculations.

Comment: I still see many lattice people recommend Creutz today.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Yeah, that's the only one I've heard!

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/388968/2451 and links therein.